# Ocaml : flatten a list if necessary

Tags: list, ocaml

I start in ocaml and I would like to know how in a recursive function of type
'a list -> int  ,

```ml
let rec int l =
   match l with
   | [] -> 0
   | hd::tl -> 10
```

the list can be flattened only if necessary
for example if [0;2;3;4] just returns the int
and if [[0];2; [3;4]], then do -> [0;2;3;4] and then return the int.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you represent `[[0];2;[3;4]]` in OCaml? why not?

Comment: sorry this is my first post, is this important to represent it in code format ?

Comment: no no, I mean you typed this list, but this is not a valid value in OCaml, because an `'a list` is a list of element of some type `'a`, but 2 and `[2]` have different types

Comment: oh yeah, this is why i want to know if i can  make an if statement in function of the type or maybe just print error of type if this is not the right type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store directly either a list or a number in a list, because lists must store values of the same type.

You can, however, declare a variant type (tagged union) for both kinds of values.

Here the type `'a lisr_or_val` represents values that are either a value of type `'a`, denoted for example `(A 3)`, or lists of values of type `'a lisr_or_val`, for example `(L [(A 3); (A 5)])`:

```
type 'a list_or_val = 
    L of 'a list_or_val list 
  | A of 'a
```

Then you access the leftmost value as follows:

```
let rec leftmost_value term = match term with
  | L ([]) -> failwith "Unexpected"
  | L (x::_) -> leftmost_value x
  | A v -> v;;
```

For example:

```
# leftmost_value (L [A 5; A 3]);;
- : int = 5
```